# Pure code builds the collection but UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout is not executed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Pure code (I didn't use the storyboard, just use code) builds the collection but UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout is not executed.

```
class Calendarview : UIView , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource  , UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    var collectionview : UICollectionView!
    override func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
    }

    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        collectionview = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.height) , collectionViewLayout: layout)

        collectionview.frame = self.frame
        collectionview.register(CalendarCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionview.dataSource = self
        collectionview.delegate = self
        self.addSubview(collectionview!)
        collectionview.reloadData()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 42
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.bounds.width / 7, height: self.bounds.height / 3)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 5
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CalendarCell
        cell.lbshow = UILabel(frame: cell.bounds)
        cell.lbshow.text = String(indexPath.row)
        cell.addSubview(cell.lbshow)
        cell.backgroundColor = .blue
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by pure code? Which function doesn't get executed?

Comment: I didn't use the storyboard, just use code

Comment: func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: self.bounds.width / 7, height: self.bounds.height / 3)
    }

Comment: firdt remove `UICollectionViewDelegate ` conformance

Comment: second `collectionview.reloadData()` totally unnecessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set delegate as `self.collectionView.delegate = self;`. `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` inherits from `UICollectionViewDelegate`. So it will called all methods of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.

Hence, You need to set `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout` to your flow layout.

```
        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
            layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
            layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
            layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
            collectionview.collectionViewLayout = layout
```